# Heroku App crashing from missing 'request-promise' Module

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, crash, dependencies

I am new to MERN stack stuff (and programming in general). I am building an app using heroku for an assignment and my proxy is having I think dependency issues.

Here is the heroku log:

```
2020-04-20T01:16:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-20T01:16:44.447430+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-20T01:16:50.175664+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087369+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087379+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087379+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087380+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087380+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'request-promise'
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087380+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087381+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087382+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087382+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087382+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087383+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087383+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:12:10)
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087384+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087384+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087384+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087385+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087385+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087386+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087386+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087387+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2020-04-20T01:16:50.087387+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-04-20T01:21:53.525467+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-20T01:21:58.716936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650366+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650395+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650395+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650395+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650396+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'request-promise'
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650396+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650396+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650397+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650397+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650398+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650398+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650398+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:12:10)
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650399+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650399+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650438+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650439+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650440+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650441+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650441+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650441+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2020-04-20T01:21:58.650441+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

I have tried "rebuilding" my package.json with `npm install request`, `npm install request-promise`, and `npm init` and pushing to my github repo then deploying it to heroku but I get the same error.

here is the top of my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var authJwtController = require('./auth_jwt');
var User = require('./Users');
var Movie = require('./Movies');
var Review = require('./Reviews');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var cors = require('cors');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const crypto = require("crypto");
var rp = require('request-promise');
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "hw4removedforprivacy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "week7a",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000 --exit",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "removedforprovacy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.9",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-http": "^0.3.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.5",
    "sinon": "^7.2.2",
    "sinon-mongoose": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/blahblaghblaghremovedforprivacy"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/blahblaghblaghremovedforprivacy"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/blahblaghblaghremovedforprivacy"
}
```

I dont know what to do... I am very confused to why the server.js runs locally but not on heroku. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

try `npm i request-promise` or `npm install request-promise -s` so it will save request-promise in your package.json. Then try to deploy

Comment: thank you for the answer. I fixed it by moving the dependency in the package.json from devDependencies to Dependencies. I dont know if thats good practice to just move things around in package.json but it worked..

Answer (score 1):

you are very close; but it seems that you left your request-promise inside the devDependencies by accident. Request-promise should be in the dependency because it is a package that you need for your application to work. **To clarify, packages under devDependencies will be removed before deployment**

Bahram is right, you need to do `npm install request-promise`. You probably did `npm install request-promise --save-dev` and as a result, it saved it under your devDependencies

Best to keep your devDependencies and dependencies separate. You may find this Heroku doc helpful => https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1376